# Azure app service thread being killed, no evidence

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a process running within a windows based azure app service which runs the plan out of memory and I'm assuming the thread is being killed by something.

I'm trying to find evidence of this happening in some sort of logging but can't, all I can see is in the metrics high memory usage and high garbage collection:

[image]

Is there anywhere I should expect to find the evidence, e.g. something I could alert on. My app does have peaky memory patterns so just looking for memory usage isn't viable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that high memory usage triggered an auto-heal event and Azure platform restarted the application.

To confirm this, you can go to the *App Service → Diagnose and solve problems → Availability and Performance → Web App Restarted*. If there was an auto-heal event, it will be shown like this:

[image: Auto-heal event description]

If this happens regularly, I would recommend to review your application memory consumption and potentially scale up the app service plan.

Comment: thanks for the reply, we've disabled auto heal just to eek a bit more memory of the box, we'd rather the request completes rather than be killed off early. We're on a P3V3 sku so can't go any bigger

Comment: also nothing shows in diagnose and solve problems when other than memory usage was high, no restarts / crashes etc seen

Comment: @mattb I see, you can also check the app service event log for any related errors. Though running a production application at 100% memory usage is not reliable, because you don't know when the application will fail to allocate a new piece of memory and throw an OutOfMemory exception. If you know what's taking the memory in this application, you can think about how it can be scaled horizontally or use an external storage for heavy data.

Comment: nothing shows in the event log, I'm hoping to see a outofmemory exception but that doesn't appear to be captured. Understood you shouldn't run close to 100% and that's being addressed elsewhere, but in the meantime I'm hoping to capture the event so we can at least alert on a failure

Comment: @mattb Understood, you can try adding an alert rule based on the Memory percentage metric. I've just remembered one more thing - did you see an instance switch when the memory level dropped? You can check this by enabling "split by instance" in the Memory Percentage chart. I wonder if Azure switched instances in the background and did not show as a platform event.